# c# nested dictionary - dictionary in a dictionary return error (KeyNotFoundException)

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary, nested

Error code occurs when I try using a nested dictionary in C# under visual studio 2012 in a asp.net web api project. this code sample is actually referenced from other supporters on stack-overflow.  Same method works fine for regular dictionary, but it does not work for nested dictionary.

-Thanks

example code:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> nest_dict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
nest_dict["a1"]["b1"] = "nest dict test string value";
```

> An exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should initialize the 'nested' dictionary first:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> nest_dict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
nest_dict["a1"] = new Dictionary<string, string>();
nest_dict["a1"]["b1"] = "nest dict test string value";
```